# Are there numpy.linalg functions that behave like tensorflow.linalg function broadcasting over the outer dims and operating on the two inner dims?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

For example if `A.shape = (100, 5, 5)`, `tf.linalg.diag(A)` will operate on the two last dims and give you shape of `(100, 5)`.

Is there a numpy version of these kind of things?

Comment: In this case, I think you're asking for: `np.diagonal(a, axis1=1, axis2=2)`

Comment: Yep, but then there is np.solve and others. Not sure if they all have this variant.

Comment: Check the docs.  I don't think there's a general rule.  `np.linalg.inv` says the input can be `(..., M, M)`.  I see the same notation in `det` and `solve`.  `np.dot` doesn't batch, `np.matmul` does.  I don't think there's much 'batching' in `scipy` solvers.  `tensorflow` may apply the 'batching' concept more systematically.